# Python Regex Negative Lookahead In Tags

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to develop a negative lookahead regex in Python to match unmatched xml style tags. I have two strings:

```
1) <TIMESTART>11:00</TIMEXSTART>. </bye> <TIMEX>not in december</TIMEX>
2) <TIMESTART>11:00</TIMEXSTART>. <TIMEX>not in december</TIMEX>
```

The regex should match

```
</bye> in the first sentence but nothing in the second one
```

Currently I have

```
re.compile(r'<\s*\/\s*[^>]*>.*?((?:<\s*\/\s*.*?>))')
```

But it always matches the second closing tag. I've tried a negative lookahead but it is not working, it matches the last closing tag (TIMEX) in the second sentence:

```
re.compile(r'<\s*\/\s*[^>]*>^(?!<\s*\/\s*.*?>).*?((?:<\s*\/\s*.*?>))')
```

Edit: This works better but it doesn't still catch the case where a string ends like:

```
....</tag1> </tag2>

re.compile(r'<\s*\/\s*[^>]*>(?!<\s*\/\s*.*?>).*?((?:<\s*\/\s*.*?>)).*?((?:<\s*[^\/]\s*.*?>))')
```

Comment: Why you don't want to match `</TIMEXSTART>` ? What do you mean by `unmatched xml style tags` ?

Comment: That was a substring of the original string that was miscopied. It is now corrected.

Comment: Can you explain why you do not use a parser? (Other than "I don't have the time to learn how that works")

Comment: could you correct this `<TIMESTART>11:00</TIMEXSTART>` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using match try replacing the content.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'<([^>]*)(\s[^>]*)?>((?!<\/?\1>).)*<\/\1>')
test_str = u"<TIMEXSTART>11:00</TIMEXSTART>. </bye> <TIMEX>not in december</TIMEX>\n<TIMEXSTART>11:00</TIMEXSTART>. <TIMEX>not in december</TIMEX>"
subst = u""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/23

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern and check against the second capturing group

```
<([^<>]*)>[^<>]*<\/\1>|(<\/[^<>]*>)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/136)

Answer (score 0):

Get the mismatched tags from group index 2.

```
<(\w+\b[^<>]*)>(?:(?!<\/?\1>).)*</\1>|(<[^<>]*>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cG7bP4/4)

- `<(\w+\b[^<>]*)>(?:(?!<\/?\1>).)*</\1>` regex would match all the properly closed tags.
- `|` OR (ie. from the remaining string)
- `(<[^<>]*>)` this would capture the remaining mismatched tags.

Comment: It seems almost there. How can this be adjusted so that it only returns the unclosed tags. In the demo it matches most of the closing tags.